# unrar folder with password (terminal)

Tags: password, directory, rar

i'm using this command to unrar folders:

```
for file in *.part01.rar; do unrar x ${file}; done;
```

but i don't know where to add the password in this command. because right now, this command wants the password for every archive in that folder.

thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From `man unrar`:

```
-p<password>
  Set password.
```

So your line would be something like:

```
for file in *.part01.rar; do unrar x -p<password> ${file}; done;
```

Comment: Can also use quotations, `-p"<password>" `

Answer (score 8):

I only `unrar` the first part (when there are part01.rar, part02.rar, etc.) and it goes itself for the rest of the files.

```
unrar x An_Awesome_Movie.part01.rar -ppassword
```

Comment: sure it is `-ppassword` not `-p password` ? also perhaps clarify which rar you use, there are two in the reposittories.

Comment: Sure, `-pYOUPASS`, so you don't have to type it on a prompt later. I've found two, unrar-free and unrar. I use unrar. If I type just `unrar` appears a menu that says: "UNRAR 5.30 beta 2 freeware".

Answer (score 1):

1. Enter to the directory containing the rar file, run below cmd:

   unrar x -p /path/to/filename.rar
2. After that, enter password into the pompt